# What can I make for breakfast that's vegan and requires very little time and effort?

Tags: recipe-request

I have a young baby and he is the only member of our household who is getting well fed these days! What can I make for breakfast in less than 15 minutes? I don't have much time for pre-prep or washing up. Bonus if it has protein and vitamins and stuff.

---

Here's an example of one thing I can make if I have bananas:

#### Banana Oat Pancakes

- 1.5 cups oats
- 1 tbsp almonds
- 1 tbsp cashews
- 1/4 tsp cinnamon
- 1 tbsp coconut sugar or jaggery
- pinch vanilla seeds
- 2-3 ripe bananas
- coconut oil for frying

1. Blend everything except bananas and oil
2. Add bananas and ~1/2 cup water and blend into a batter
3. Fry on a hot iron pan using coconut oil
4. Serve with peanut butter, jam, vegan yogurt, maple syrup or whatever you like

---

I need other easy peasy options

Answer (score 5):

Breakfast is one of the fastest and easiest things to make!

## Hot Porridge

Lots of fine-cut [cereal grains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cereal_grains) can be prepared into [porridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porridge) by **just pouring boiling water on them**.

[image: a bowl of oats with apple, bannana, and berries in it]

Consider, for example, "Quick Oats'. But wikipedia has a list of a few hundred different grains you can use to make porridge:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_porridges

Besides changing the type of grain, top it with fresh fruit, nuts, jam, coconut yogurt, etc..

Add a handful of nuts on-top for protein.

## Cold Cereal

You could buy a boxed cereal and **just pour (oat) milk on it**.

[image: photo of corn flakes in a bowl with milk]

Add a handful of fruit or berries, if you'd like.

Protip: you don't have to buy boxed cerials. You can make your own [muesli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muesli) or [granola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granola), both of which can be very high-protein!

## Fresh Fruit

Eat a banana. Or an apple. Or both.

If you want to get fancy, buy a bunch of different fruits. Once a week, cut them all up, put them in 7 jars and store them in your freezer. The night before, just move from freezer to fridge.

[image: photo of cut fruit in a jar]

## Bread & Butter

Put some vegan butter on bread. Or jam, if you want something sweet.

[image: photo of two slices of bread with jam on them on a plate]

Or dip the bread in olive oil, [za'atar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Za%27atar), [tahini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahini) and/or [dibs (date syrup)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_honey) as they do in the middle-east.

For high-protein, spread it with [baked beans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baked_beans) or [marmite (yeast extract)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marmite) as they do in the UK. Or [peanut butter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut_butter) as the do in the US. Or [hummus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hummus).

## Trail Mix

Put some (unsalted) nuts and seeds (eg peanuts, sunflour seeds, pumpkins seeds, cashews, almonds, walnuts etc) and dried fruit (eg raisins, banana chips, cranberries, dates, apricots, etc) in a bag.

[image: photo of mixed nuts and dried fruits]

A few handfuls makes a great, fast, high-protein breakfast.

Comment: Thanks! I should really try putting together a nice trail mix/muesli

Answer (score 2):

I see that you don't have much time for preparation and my own personal favourite: 'Overnight Oats' has pretty negligible prep time, although it does need to go in the fridge overnight...

---

**Overnight Oats**

- One large banana (mashed)
- Two tablespoons of Chia seeds
- Sprinkling of cinnamon (more or less as preferred)
- Three quarter cup of rolled oats (more or less as preferred)
- Almond milk sufficient to cover dry ingredients (Soy / Macadamia / Oat milks are also fine)
- Dollop of Vanilla Extract

Place all of the ingredients into your usual breakfast cereal bowl, stir it all together and then place the cereal bowl (covered) in the fridge overnight. For bonus points top the oats with blueberries before eating...

---

Enjoy!

Comment: Yum :) I like grated apple plus a dash of lemon juice in overnight oats, but the apple is best added in the morning rather than the night before.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I can suggest from the top of my head
(I may add more later on as I know the struggle being parent myself)

---

### Tofu scramble

I won't list any measures here as you can adjust the dose to meet your taste/needs + you can always store the leftovers as they are still going to be good for a while (when stored properly).

Fry for a minute (or if you want to go oil free, saute with water/vegetable broth):

- Onions, diced (it doesn't even have to be diced, sliced works well for me)
- Garlic, minced (optional as many people are being careful due to the smell)

Meanwhile mash the tofu and add it to the pan.
In this step you can add some spices/herbs like turmeric, black pepper, red pepper, salt, nooch, cayenne pepper, fenugreek - basically whatever you want.

This on its own is a nice breakfast already, which you can enjoy with some quick made sauce/dressing (tahini/peanut butter/sour cream/avocado/etc..). However you can add veggies like paprika, tomatoes, spinach, kale, broccoli, okras, mushrooms, carrots, zucchini, bok choy, sweet potatoes..
 This is how I usually get rid of my leftovers ;)

You can add various things like black sesame, hemp seeds, almonds, walnuts, etc. Scrambled tofu is very forgiving and it will really taste good even if you don't have much time to bother with the ingredients and dosage. It can even go on a piece of bread.

[image: scrambled tofu with red peppers and broccoli]

---

Expectations for the breakfast really depends on the culture and region of the world, so I assume that some people may find my suggestions a bit weird.

**You could also consider**:

- **Fresh pasta** - it boils very fast and you can consume it with bunch of greens like rocket salad + some balsamic vinegar or a pre made sauce, even a small can of lentils
- **Polenta** - many of them are done in less than 5 minutes
- **CousCous/Bulgur/Quinoa** - cooking time is usually 5 to 10 minutes and meanwhile you can bake some veggies in airfryer, fry them in a pan or simply use some canned product like ratatouille :)

[image: couscous with peppers and edamame]

[image: fresh pasta with broccoli]

Answer (score 1):

We make our own bread, so that's always available, so no prep time there. I am on a peanut butter and banana sandwich breakfast kick lately.
It's quick and stays with me.
Vegan since 1989

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any bread making tips? I can never seem to get a good rise here (I live in South India)

Comment: Well we use a Zojirushi bread machine ... you might have to tweak the recipe ... less salt, more sugar, or more yeast. In my part of the world (SE USA) I've had to use less yeast and a bit more salt. You might want to use less salt since salt is a yeast inhibitor.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a bread machine might be a big help